# Is it possible to create a binary RNG using hardware?

Tags: hardware, random-number

I have successfully created a binary random number generator using embedded software, but I would like to know if it is possible to get +1 and -1 with hardware?

Comment: Welcome! What have your research brought up so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: It is certainly possible, but depends on "how random" you need the numbers to be, how much engineering you're willing to do to get a stream of random bits, and how involved you want to get in the post-processing to filter out statistical bias in the noise.  There are systems from amplifying thermal noise all the way up to Cloudflare's 100-lava lamp PRNG seed generator.

Comment: Anything you can do in software can also be done in hardware. How do you think the software actually does a computation?

Comment: Clarify whether you mean PRNG - pseudorandom number generator, OK for Monte Carlo but not OK for crypto, which meets tests of uniformity but is settable and predictable, or a TRNG - true random number generator, suitable for crypto as it's (ideally) completely unpredictable, which makes it less suitable for some Monte Carlo uses.

Comment: Do you mean 1 and 0? +1 and -1 implies 0 inbetween i.e. trinary. (Which is also possible, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for the great responses. For my need pseudorandom is fine. My research has yielded nothing of interest. I must be searching for the wrong terms. I do find a lot of RNG circuits that give 1-100, etc.. but I am looking for +1 , and -1 such that the bias should be 0.

Comment: Why can't you just transform the data in post? I.e. scale 1-100 to fit in the range of -1 to +1 (1=>-1, 50=>0, 100=>1).

Answer (score 2):

There is a multitude of possible implementations. The choice mainly depends on the "quality" of randomness expected, whether the generator has to be truly random or merely pseudorandom, whether the implementation is on a chip or in a discrete circuit, etc.

A relatively simple old-school discrete circuit has two amplified Zener noise sources, band-limited (obviously), each passed through a zero-crossing detector - a zero-comparator. The output of one detector clocks a D flip-flop. The other detector provides the data to the flip-flop. A couple (2-3) additional D FF stages de-glitch the data. The offset of both zero-crossing detectors has to be nulled, although when using a dual comparator - one for clock, one for the data - there is IIRC a self-compensating mechanism inherent.

Instead of two sources, a single source can be used, with a fixed clock. The clock has to be maintained *below* the average frequency of the single source. This is a disadvantage when compared to two-source system, where the bandwidth of both channels is similar, and the scheme is self-clocking at an optimal rate.

Finally, a shift register captures the bits that make up a random data word, and each time it's full, the output is fed into a FIFO. Any device that then needs random data can be reading from the FIFO at a fixed rate. As long as that rate is lower than the average output transition rate of the zero detector, divided by the word size, the consumer gets a nice stream of random words.

These random words can be formatted into uniformly distributed floating point numbers between -1 and +1, using any common algorithm for doing so (i.e. the "magic" that takes random integers and spews out uniformly distributed floats). For simplicity's sake, a long random word can be converted to floating point directly, by treating it as if it were a fixed point number. This maintains the uniformity of the distribution. If the fixed point word is long enough, even very small absolute values - down to 1 ULP - will appear with expected frequency. For double precision, the random word needs to be a couple kilobits long, since the exponent is 11 bits wide. For single precision, a couple hundred bits suffice.